# To find location based on time elapsed in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps

I am working on plotting a multi-colored route using Google Maps API. It should plot different colors based on time elapsed between two points. For this I am trying to find location after user enters time taken to reach that location.

Is there any method to do so?

Comment: The user enters locations and time for those locations?

Comment: no. He just enters start and end locations and time elapsed to reach a  particular location. From that time I need to find the current location.

Comment: to calculate this you need 2 more details: the route taken by the user and the average speed

Comment: the route taken by user is the route we get while using google directions between two points. And average speed can be calculated from google directions response.

Comment: I need latitude and longitude values of the current location

Comment: You mean you want to [animate the marker along the route](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_animate_marker_directions.html)?